# Short story about pink animals that are born like pink peppers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This man crash lands on a planet with two species of animals: brown and pink. The brown animals are afraid of the pink ones and the pink ones welcome the man but exhibit strange behaviors. One takes on the characteristics of one of the deceased crew women. He eats the pink peppers and soon is laid into the ground for pink peppers to grow out of him. The pink things looked like monkeys and pigs. The brown animals were the same but were afraid of the pink ones. They stayed away from them.

Comment: Wow, you don't usually see such creepy body text following such an adorable subject line.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to remember any details on what the animals looked like do you? It seems most of my generic searches, involving pink animals/aliens/creatures, results in alot of "adult oriented" sci-fi.

Comment: For the second time today, going to say it sounds like early Robert Sheckley.

Answer (score 6):

My Thing Friday by Brian Lumley.

From a [review](https://gruesomedetails.wordpress.com/2009/12/26/my-thing-friday-review/):

> Brian Lumley’s My Thing Friday from the anthology of terror and the
>   macabre Dark Delicacies narrates the tale of Greg Griffiths, the lone
>   survivor of the Albert Einstein: The space ship hailing from the
>   Greater Mars Orbital Station.
>
> ...
>
> However, the story is much more about his interactions with the beings
>   of the planet rather than a tale of survival. **Humanlike pink
>   creatures** roam the forests surrounding the clearing where the space
>   ship landed, and birdlike pink creatures and **hog-like pink
>   creatures** meander around the wreckage.
>
> Griffiths, being a simple engineer, does not realize until it is too
>   late how these docile humanlike pink creatures are the dominant
>   species on the planet. His voice journal ends abruptly with his dying
>   words and the reader finally realizes why the humanlike pink creatures
>   held such a reverence for the dead, including Griffiths’ crew members.

Comment: There's a chance this is right, but is there any mention of the peppers?

Comment: So I looked the story up in Google Books and was able to read most of it, and there is, actually it's carrots! They're described as "purple carrots" that taste "like a cross between chili peppers and green onions".