# Anthology story where crew crash lands on planet, lone survivor meets brown and pink animals

Tags: story-identification

I read this short science fiction story years ago between 2004 and 2007. Thing is I can't remember the year.

The story itself revolves around a man who crash-lands on a world with his crew, him being the only survivor. He buries his mates and observes his surroundings. There are two types of the same animals on this planet; brown and pink. The brown animals stay away from him and the pinks, but the pinks approach him with curiosity.

He finds these pink pepper things and eats them. They make him kind of sick to the stomach but nothing bad. He notices the same peppers growing out of the graves he dug. One night he finds a primate looking pink animal dressed in one of the female crews underwear making an advance to him.

He then begins to realize the brown animals are afraid of the pink ones but before he can do anything about it his body begins to ache and shut down. He realizes too late that the pink peppers were the pink animals themselves, or they're eggs at least.

It ends with him being buried so the pink peppers can grow out of him, hopefully making the first pink humanoid.

I read this in an anthology book with other stories. Thing is I don't remember which one. I thought it was the mammoth book of horror stories or mammoth book of monsters but I cannot locate. So it must have been in one of the either best horror or science fictions stories releases around that time. If anyone can help please do. This has been bothering me for years now. One other thing: I thought the name of the story was "Homeward Bound" or something of the like, but my searches have yielded no results.

Comment: Same story as [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102270/short-story-about-pink-animals-that-are-born-like-pink-peppers?rq=1) it seems. No answer to that one either.

Comment: In fact, I believe you might be the same poster? If so, please try to [merge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts. Good luck.

Comment: Answered the other one, it's My Thing Friday by Brian Lumley.

Comment: @smooshie Might as well post your answer on this question, too.